# Préfixe pour exprimer l'excès de quelque chose

Tags: vocabulaire, préfixes

Lors d'une discussion fictive dans ma tête, j'ai pensé à une réplique insultante à l'encontre de mon adversaire illusoire, laquelle sonnait comme quelque chose du genre "Le feu était rouge pour toi espèce de daltonien poly-chromosomé !".

Outre le fait que cette expression n'est pas à sortir d'un contexte strictement mental et privé, cela m'a poussé à me poser la question quant à sa validité. Effectivement, les êtres humains et une écrasante majorité des êtres vivants **sont** poly-chromosomés.

**Existe-t-il un préfixe exprimant l’excès que je pourrais utiliser dans cette situation ?**

Je pourrais facilement utiliser les mots "trop" ou "excessivement", mais cela romprait le flow de mon insulte imaginaire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il y a tout simplement le préfixe *sur-*:

> surpêche
>
> surexposition
>
> surdimensionné

On pourrait donc imaginer un néologisme *surchromosomé*.

Answer (score 0):

Il existe un préfixe parfait : « sur- » ;

> (TLFi) B. [Le dér. est un verbe ou un subst. désignant un procès (subst. déverbal, dér. morphol. ou fonctionnant avec un verbe support); il exprime le fait de dépasser une limite]

Je ne sais pas cependant si l'on devrait écrire « sur-chromosomé » ou « surchromosomé ».